# Converting JSON data downloaded in CSV

Tags: python-3.x, weka, twitter-oauth

I have downloaded Twitter data in JSON format but in CSV file, unfortunately, I am unable to retrieve the data from the csv file. I need a code or a converter to read the data from the file and take the particular headers.

https://youtu.be/IRMZ1xDYHvg

Please watch the video and give me the code to get particular data using the coordinates

Comment: By "JSON format but in CSV file" do you mean the file is *named* as CSV (e.g. ``something.csv``) but *contains* JSON format (e.g. ``[1, 2, 3]``)?

Comment: Yes, the format is JSON but the file is named as .csv

Comment: Are you aware that the file name (including its extension) has no bearing on how to process its content? You can just load it with a regular ``json`` decoder, e.g. ``json.load(open("something.csv"))``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't know how to process the data. Please help

Comment: https://youtu.be/IRMZ1xDYHvg

Please watch the video and give me the code to get particular data using the coordinates

Comment: @HermanthKumar Please include the relevant code and minimal input required to reproduce your question *in the question itself*. See the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Reading file,

```
In [11]: import requests

In [12]: f = requests.get(url) . # whatever extension you have

In [13]: data = f.content
```

Converting data to `json`,

```
In [14]: import json

In [15]: json_data = json.loads(data)
```

Now you can use for loop to manupulate fields from `json_data`,

```
In [19]: for key, val in json_data.items():
    ...:     print(key, val)
    ...:
```

Comment: @downvoter can you please explain what is wrong here, so I can correct.

Comment: I need the code to take particular data from the file.

Comment: https://youtu.be/IRMZ1xDYHvg

Please watch the video and give me the code to get particular data using the coordinates

Comment: I am unable to open the csv file

Comment: @HemanthKumar can you please post sample file contents here, so we can help you.

Comment: I want to delimit the twitter data from json file. Please post the code to delimit the data